# Can I include external HTML files as headers/footers when rendering to PDF with PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I'm trying to set up a way to render HTML files to PDF.  The HTML files are dynamically generated, and have separate HTML files for their headers and footers, which need to be attached to each page.

Am I able to get PhantomJS pick up these separate files and display them in the header and footer sections?  I can get headers and footers when I have the HTML for them in the javascript files I pass to PhantomJS, as in the example code I've included, but I'm not familiar with HTML, CSS, Javascript (and Node?) enough to know if there is a clear way to do what I want.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

//set the page size and add headers & footers
page.paperSize = {
  format: 'A4',
  margin: '.5cm',
  header: {
    height: "1cm",
    contents: phantom.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
    return "<h1 style='font-size:12.0; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,FreeSans,sans-serif'>Header <span style='float:right'>" + pageNum + " / " + numPages + "</span></h1>";
    })
  },
  footer: {
    height: "1cm",
    contents: phantom.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
    return "<h1 style='font-size:12.0; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,FreeSans,sans-serif'>Footer <span style='float:right'>" + pageNum + " / " + numPages + "</span></h1>";
    })
  }
}

//open the page
page.open('tools.html', function() {
  page.render('woki2.pdf');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

It works to add the headers and footers but requires inline styling (which I believe I can get around with [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502677/phantomjs-dosent-render-footers-with-a-custom-styles)) but I would prefer to be able to pick up external HTML files, so that a) different headers and footers can be used depending on the type of file being converted; and b) so that the HTML files can be edited easily without changing the JS files.

This is an example of the header HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function subst() {
        var vars = {};
        var x = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for (var i in x) {
            var z = x[i].split('=', 2);
            vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);
        }
        var x = ['frompage', 'topage', 'page', 'webpage', 'section', 'subsection', 'subsubsection', 'date', 'time'];
        for (var i in x) {
            var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="border:0; margin: 0;" onload="subst()">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Generated by *person* on <span class="date"></span> <span class="time"></span></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
                Page <span class="page"></span> of <span class="topage"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

While I am aware I can achieve a similar thing to what is represented there with the first example, I'd prefer to have the files separated if possible.

Comment: You mean external custom template files?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'll add an example of the HTML file I mean to the question as I probably should've included it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way , simply read header.html file assign it to one variable and use it in header part

```
var fs    = require('fs');
var headerContent   = fs.read('header.html');
header: {height: "1cm",contents: headerContent}
```